# Newark Airport to central New Jersey on a student's budget

Tags: public-transport, budget, airport-transfer, ewr, new-jersey

I need to get from Newark Airport (EWR) to East Brunswick NJ at the end of December of this year, but I see that to take a cab would cost more than $60 which is a quite a lot for my budget.

Are there any shuttles or other options that are more economical?

Comment: Shared airport shuttle might be the way to go.

Comment: @phoog Do you have any companies that you would recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is from official New Jersey transit:

http://www.njtransit.com/sf/sf_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TripPlannerItineraryFrom

The Average regular price $15.25 from Newark Airport Rail station to New Brunswick

[image]

And from New Brunswick to to East Brunswick, according to rome2rio the other 2 possible options either bus line 811($2 to $4) or Uber ($9 to $13)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The NJ Transit train would be around $15, depending on time of day to New Brusnwick.

Then, there is at least one bus from the train station to East Brunswick area.

If you're going to Rutgers, it's not far from the train station, depending on the campus.